# Как пользоваться Drools standalone?

Tags: java

Кто пользовался процессором правил Drools?
Из того, что я прочитал - это набор ява-библиотек, которые интегрируются в проект. После чего можно вызывать Друлз из программы, получать обработанные правила и радоваться жизни.

Но тут мне сказали, что Друлз должен быть стендалон - то есть отдельная версия, без необходимости писать ява-код, с которым будет взаимодействовать друлз-машина.

И тут у меня начались непонятки.
Так как я даже не представляю, как друлз может быть отдельным приложением - а откуда он должен брать тогда входные данные и куда выводить результат?..

Как работать с друлз стендалон. Где можно о таком почитать?

Comment: эм. он не нужен, чтобы писать свои рулы и использовать их в коде.

Comment: так я так и понял концепцию друлз: берем наше приложение в стиле "если условиеN выполняется, то запускается функцияN", и переписываем его под друлз так, что часть проверки условий выходит за рамки джавы в файл правил, обрабатываемых друлзом. А сами функции (то есть логика, достигающаяся выполнением условий) все еще на яве.

Comment: http://drools.org/ - мне нужно, как на картинках из превью. Из прочитанного там, вижу, что мне нужен Drools Workbench. Вот только где этот Воркбренч в скачанном (оттуда же) архиве?

Comment: `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8001:8001 -d --name drools-workbench jboss/drools-workbench:latest` и потом переходите http://localhost:8080/drools-wb

Comment: подробнее [тут](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/drools-workbench/)